# Error Message : Query has no destination for result data

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql, stored-functions

I am new to postgreSQL. I am trying to convert `SQL store procedure` into `postgreSQL store function.` I tried Like below store function created successfully but when I am trying to execute I am getting following error message. I am not getting where I need to replace `PERFORM`.

```
ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
HINT:  If you want to discard the results of a SELECT, use PERFORM instead.
```

**SQL Store Procedure**

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[roomType]
    @intInstId int
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        nClientRoomTypeID,sClientRTDesc,sClientRTName,sClientRTCode
    FROM 
        ClientRoomType
    WHERE 
        ClientRoomType.nInstID=@intInstId
    ORDER BY 
        ClientRoomType.sClientRTCode
END
GO
```

**PostgreSQl Store Function**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION roomType (int_inst_id int)
RETURNS VOID
AS $$
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        nclient_room_type_id,sclient_rt_desc,sclient_rt_name,sclient_rt_code
    FROM 
        clientroomtype
    WHERE 
        clientroomtype.ninst_id=int_inst_id
    ORDER BY 
        clientroomtype.sclient_rt_code;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're attempting to return the query result with your function. You actually do not need `plpgsql` language for this, but in case you need it for somthing else, use this syntax:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION roomType (int_inst_id int)
RETURNS TABLE (res_nclient_room_type_id INT,res_sclient_rt_desc TEXT,res_sclient_rt_name TEXT, res_sclient_rt_code TEXT)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY 
    SELECT 
        nclient_room_type_id,sclient_rt_desc,sclient_rt_name,sclient_rt_code
    FROM 
        clientroomtype
    WHERE 
        clientroomtype.ninst_id=int_inst_id
    ORDER BY 
        clientroomtype.sclient_rt_code;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

How to use it?

```
SELECT * FROM roomType(1);
```

Since I do not have your data, I cannot test it. But it follows this principle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f ()
RETURNS TABLE (b boolean, x int)
AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT TRUE, 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

SELECT * FROM f();

 b | x 
---+---
 t | 1
(1 Zeile)
```

Comment: I tried this syntax I am getting this error `ERROR:  column reference "nclient_room_type_id" is ambiguous
LINE 2:   nclient_room_type_id,sclient_rt_desc,sclient_rt_name,sclie...
          ^
DETAIL:  It could refer to either a PL/pgSQL variable or a table column`

Comment: yes its working but result getting in this format `(1,"TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED","TEMPORARILY NOT ASSIGNED",000)` why column is not desplaying

Comment: I will update my question again with a hint :-) Try : `select * from roomType (1);`

Comment: I added screenshot of result

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176416/discussion-between-jim-jones-and-hkak).